# Who is this third character and what is her connection?

Tags: toradora, the-familiar-of-zero, shakugan-no-shana

I have had this image for a while now

[image]

I know the brown hair in the middle is supposed to be [Taiga Aisaka](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rv4PX.jpg) from *Toradora* and the pink hair on the right is [Louise de La Vallière](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGW22.png) from *The Familiar of Zero*, but who is the third character with the red hair on the left? And is there some sort of connection between all 3 characters who are in different anime to make them almost look identical? (e.g. the light in the hair and the face seems to match perfectly yet the shirt on either side doesn't)

Comment: kinda look like Shana IMO

Comment: @OshinoShinobu It's definitely Shana (even image search says so). Reference to the fact that the three characters have the same personality, seiyuu, etc, and the fact that J.C. Staff is rather lazy with this kind of thing.

Comment: @LoganM when i did the google reverse image search i just got Taiga but i remembered Louise looking like Taiga but with pink hair, i just know Shana from dvd covers and she doesn't really look like Taiga or Louise but it could be the covers have a different art design. you seem to have also answered the rest of my question so you just being lazy in not posting an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think she looks like Shana from Shakugan no Shana

[image]

All of them has similar trait, small stature, and tsundere. All of them also has same seiyuu, she's [Rie Kugimiya](http://www.anime-planet.com/people/rie-kugimiya). And all of them also produced by J.C. Staff.

The reason of why they look similar probably because (as [@LoganM](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/24/logan-m) says) J.C. Staff is rather lazy with this kind of thing. They also have similar art and animation style among their series even when they have different Character Designer.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on [Shinobu's answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/17143/1587):

These three (Shana, Taiga, and Louise, in that order) are commonly referred to as the "big three" tsundere characters.  They each take a different perspective on what "tsundere" implies, but are the "guideline" characters when creating a tsundere.

These characters were all voiced by [Rie Kugimiya](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rie_Kugimiya), who has probably voiced the most tsundere characters of any voice actor.

Sometimes, due to fan's personal opinion, the "big three" is stated with other characters, often from [Rie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rie_Kugimiya)'s portfolio.  Common replacements are Nagi (Hayate the Combat Butler), and Aria (Aria the Scarlet Ammo).

However, it is generally accepted that the three listed earlier are the "big three", irreplaceable even with the passage of time.  (Since fans have decided that "tsundere" is defined by the three's combined personality, and not the other way around.)

To dive into the strange side of anime for a moment; the "fans" I have been referring to are mostly those gathered around the [TsunDere GiRlS RuLeS](https://www.facebook.com/TsundereGirlsRules) facebook page, and the corresponding wiki, http://tsunderegirlsrules.wikia.com.

(As a side note, Shakugan no Shana is well worth watching.  (My favorite anime.))

Reference(s):

- http://tsunderegirlsrules.wikia.com/wiki/Tsundere_Girls